# Flutter FirebaseMessaging - Device token only showing up in simulator

Tags: ios, flutter

The app I'm building requires push notifications. Naturally I followed all the docs from Firebase on how to add the right code and enable things for iOS.
When I run the sim(iPhone 12) it works on both Android and iOS (device token shows up as text to test), but when I release a dev IPA for my physical device it fails to show the device ID.
What am I missing here?

Any help and thinking along appreciated :)

Comment: have you allowed   noitifcations for that app on device ?

Comment: Yes, but still, even without allowing on the device itself, it should fetch the device token. I just tested it on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It had to do when distributing the app through xcode. The PPN needed to be manually added.

Comment: Can you show the code?